# Taping the Light on a Freezer

Tags: halacha, shabbat, how-to, appliances

For people who don't use electricity on Shabbos, what do you do with the freezer light? With the fridge, it's easier because I can just tape the notch that controls the light, but with the freezer, it's so humid that neither Scotch tape, nor packing tape, nor duct tape actually sticks to the notch.

This isn't really a halachic question, but rather one of how practically one does this, but listed the halacha tag, since it is related to a halachic issue of opening the freezer door.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the freezer, but one approach is to just unscrew the light bulb if you can reach it.  That's what my family has always done.

You can leave it loosely hanging in the socket if you want to put it back in for during the week, though unless it's in a dark basement it's probably easier to just leave it out all the time.

This only works with basic freezers.  Fancier freezers sometimes do other things, like turn on an electronic display, when you open the door, so taking out the light bulb doesn't solve all your problems.

Comment: Many basic freezers don't even have light bulbs.

Answer (score 4):

If your freezer is anything like mine it doesn't have an actual bulb.

One way round this is to use a powerful magnet which cuts the circuit without harming the freezer in anyway.

The Federation Beis Din in London have a dedicated technology site to deal with various home appliances and the halachic pitfalls that sometime follow on Shabbos.

Try taking a look [here](https://www.federation.org.uk/how-to-kosher-a-fridge/). Hatzlacha!

Answer (score 4):

I use velcro tape. If you dry the area on both sides of the switch, you can get the tape with the hooks or loops to stick. Then, every week before Shabbos it's just a matter of attaching the other piece across.

There are items manufactured specifically for this which are sold in most judaica stores.

I would suggest only using 3M brand, not the junk you can find in a local dollar store.