# Can I open my fridge on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, electricity

When my fridge is off opening it causes it to turn on (after I close the door). When my fridge is on opening it causes it to turn off (while the door is open).

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-do-you-do-if-you-forgot-to-turn-off-the-refrigerator-light-before-shabbat

Comment: And this: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115134/taping-the-light-on-a-freezer

Comment: This site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: There are no rabbis well versed in any laws on todays time. The internet is the new rabbi.